# How to run ruby which require a ruby library(mcollective) from java using jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am trying to run the following ruby script.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mcollective'
```

from following java code

```
ScriptingContainer ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
        Object result = ruby.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE,"/opt/ruby_test.rb");
```

But I am getting the following exception.

```
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
  require at jar:file:/tmp/target/dependency-jars/jruby-complete-1.7.3.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at /opt/ruby_test.rb:3
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- mcollective
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:133)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1264)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1309)
    at mcollective.mcollective.run(mcollective.java:18)
    at mcollective.mcollective.main(mcollective.java:12)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- mcollective
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
    at RUBY.require(jar:file:/tmp/target/dependency-jars/jruby-complete-1.7.3.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
    at RUBY.(root)(/opt/ruby_test.rb:3)
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing mcollective-client ruby gems using rvm.